# Cloning a repo based on Angular CLI

Tags: angular-cli

I created a small Angular 2 app based off the Angular 2 CLI. After putting it on GitHub and then cloning it on my laptop (both MacOS), *ngserve* will not complete. Here are the last three lines it displays before hanging up:

at Storage.finished (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:39:16)

at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:78:16

at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:445:3)

As far as I can tell, I updated node and the angularCLI to the same version on both machines. Is there something in the package.JSON file I should change?  BTW, I added the .idea folder to my .gitignore file so it shouldn't be an issue with Webstorm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found my mistake. I had not run the following lines in my machines' local packages:

```
rm -rf node_modules dist tmp
npm install --save-dev angular-cli@latest
npm install
ng init
```

Works like a charm now that I've done that for each machine.